# How to capture writes and reads to a device file

Tags: c

I would like to capture writes and reads to a device file /dev/xxx. Is this possible?  For network traffic, I have used libpcap earlier. Is there a similar library available to capture traffic of non-network device file?

Comment: AFAIK, you need different methods for different devices. For example, for a serial port device (ttyACM*) you will need a serial port library. For a hard disc, you may need a library raw filesystem R/W.

Answer (score 0):

#### Basic Sniffer using sockets

I make offer see [this page](https://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-c-linux/)

To `code` a very simply sniffer in C the steps would be :

1. Create a raw socket.
2. Put it in a `recvfrom` loop and receive data on it.

A raw socket when put in `recvfrom` loop receives all incoming packets. This is because it is not bound to a particular address or port.

```
sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);
while(1)
{
data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , &saddr_size);
}
```

The buffer will hold the data sniffed or picked up. The sniffing part is actually complete over here.

The following `code` shows an example of such a sniffer. Note that it sniffs only incoming packets.

```
int sock_raw;
int tcp=0,udp=0,icmp=0,others=0,igmp=0,total=0,i,j;
struct sockaddr_in source,dest;

int main()
{
    int saddr_size , data_size;
    struct sockaddr saddr;
    struct in_addr in;

    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536); //Its Big!

    if(logfile==NULL) printf("Unable to create file.");
    printf("Starting...\n");
    //Create a raw socket that shall sniff
    sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(sock_raw < 0)
    {
        printf("Socket Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
        //Receive a packet
        data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , &saddr_size);
        if(data_size <0 )
        {
            printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
            return 1;
        }

        // Now save packet in a file
    }
    close(sock_raw);
    printf("Finished");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mohammadreza, I am looking for a non-socket device like I2C